# Transform Excel files to the existing database via the form in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I has not a lot of experience in VBA programming. What I need - is the possibility to create a simple form to extract some Excel file to the defined table by adding the records. 
Could you please tell me what function or a set of functions can be used in this case:
to open the Excel file,
define the spreadsheet,
extract data
insert them to the db table.

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,
Greg.

Comment: I'm pretty sure access has an excel import wizard....

Comment: I'm pretty sure since he's asking about VBA, he wants to do this programmatically so he doesn't have to run through the import tool every time he wants new data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://www.mvps.org/access/general/gen0008.htm) web site to get a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In your access database, create a module with the following code to import a spreadsheet:

```
Function import()

basedir = "INSERT YOUR SPREADSHEET HERE"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            "TABLENAME", _
            basedir, _
            False
End Function
```

VBA Code to select and define a range should be fairly simple, and I do not have it to hand, if you still need help with this let me know and I will edit this in when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book that I still find useful called 'Integrating Excel and Access' published by O'Reilly ((c) 2006; ISBN 0596009739). Still in publication (check Amazon) and worth the price if you are doing a lot of interaction between Excel and Access.